# npm install failed because of virtual directory

Tags: node.js, git

I'm trying to setup a new project which is a git repo stored on a virtual drive (wuala).
Is it possible that this is not possible? Because when I try npm install I get the following error:

```
node.js:815
    var cwd = process.cwd();
                      ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
    at Function.startup.resolveArgv0 (node.js:815:23)
    at startup (node.js:58:13)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: Not clear: which project is stored on a virtual drive? Yours? Or a library you're including? Is that error coming from your app, or NPM? Can you post some code?

Comment: I created a package.json on a virtual HD (wuala) & tried npm install which returns the above error (that's the core problem)

Comment: your operating system?

Comment: macintosch newb user

Comment: I don't know what's a "virtual HD" and I don't have a Wuala account to test. Can you provide some more information? Does Wuala work like Dropbox, that creates a new folder on your home directory?

Comment: Ye Wuala is the same as dropbox (only diff=encryption happens clientside)

Comment: Are files encrypted also while on your disk?

Comment: They are encrypted when synced with the server I think

Comment: I hoped that I could work on the virtual directory. So that when I logged out of wuala, the folders removed (but I don't think that it's possible)

Comment: And if you ask me what I mean by virtual directory -> all the files that are saved by wuala (from a different pc for example). But not downloaded locally

Comment: In that case, I have a feeling that the software is working weirdly and you simply can't use Node with that. Use Dropbox instead?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so the issue was node not finding the current working directory. I didn't know it was only a virtual directory, after downloading the folder locally it works.

Now if only there is way to download the folder locally every time wuala is running & to be deleted afterwards...

Comment: I had the similar issue. Moved the folder to a real drive and now it works. Rather weird implementation imho.

Answer (score 1):

Could the problem be that Wuala doesn't accept empty folders?  This topic seems to suggest non-standard behavior when it comes to empty folders:

https://support.wuala.com/forums/topic/wuala-does-not-accept-an-empty-folder-on-my-lacie-2big-as-sync-partner/

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue today and I don't think its related to the file system being virtual or not. The answer is really simple and weird.

I followed these steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open a Terminal and cd to a directory (let's say `/home/user/dir`)
2. Delete the directory from your file manager (`nautilus` in my case)
3. The console still shows :

`user@user-PC:~/dir$`

although the directory doesn't exist.

4. Run a node command. I ran `sudo npm update -g cordova`

You get the above error. So, the solution is as simple as being in a directory which exists and then executing the node command.